# Change Ubuntu Onboard Keyboard Layout from Terminal

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am planning to change the layout of my keyboard from Small to Compact on terminal. I used `onboard --layout=Small.onboard` but it was not changing.

[image]

Can you help me to get the correct snippet to change the layout of my keyboard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make it small:

```
gsettings set org.onboard layout '/usr/share/onboard/layouts/Small.onboard'
```

To make it compact (which is default):

```
gsettings reset org.onboard layout
```

Comment: You are my savior!! :) thanks a lot Gunner Hjalmarsson

Comment: I already did!! thank you so much, been searching for a month in google and you answer it in just an hour, haha! thanks Pal!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and found that the command line options will work, but only if the onboard process isn't already running.

You can accomplish this by killing it first:

```
killall onboard
onboard -l Small
```

Using the `-m` option to allow multiple instances also works: a new keyboard will open with the options specified. But any existing keyboards will still be open, and you'll end up with multiple onboard icons in the tray.